# Simplification of a product of trigonometric functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have this expression

```
2 Csc[2 y[x2]] Sech[x[x2]]^2 (Cos[y[x2]]^4 Cosh[x[x2]]^8 Sin[y[x2]]^4)^(1/4)
```

which is 1. But Mathematica doesn't do the simplification. I know that Mathematica doesn't simplify square roots very well. What would be the conditions I must give?

Comment: Maybe `TrigExpand@PowerExpand[expr]`

Comment: or `TrigReduce@PowerExpand[expr]`.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. For example, the expression is `-1` for `{y[x2]->-π/4, x[x2]->0}`.

Comment: The problem is that it is not 1. Sometimes it is -1. This can be easily checked by plotting it.

Answer (score 2):

The following works.

```
FullSimplify[2 Csc[2 y[x2]] Sech[x[x2]]^2 (Cos[y[x2]]^4 Cosh[x[x2]]^8 Sin[y[x2]]^4)^(1/4), 
Assumptions -> y[x2] \[Element] Reals && x[x2] \[Element] Reals]
```

> ```
> 1/Sign[Cos[y[x2]] Sin[y[x2]]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This gives 1.

Define the expression.

```
expr = 2 Csc[
   2 y[x2]] Sech[
    x[x2]]^2 (Cos[y[x2]]^4 Cosh[x[x2]]^8 Sin[y[x2]]^4)^(1/4)
```

And then

```
expr // Factor // TrigExpand // PowerExpand
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FullSimplify[2 Csc[2 y[x2]] Sech[x[x2]]^2 (Cos[y[x2]]^4 Cosh[x[x2]]^8 Sin[y[x2]]^4)^(1/4),
  Element[_,Reals]]
PiecewiseExpand[%,Reals]
```

> ```
> 1/Sign[Cos[y[x2]] Sin[y[x2]]]
>
> Piecewise[{{-1, Cos[y[x2]]*Sin[y[x2]] < 0}, {1, Cos[y[x2]]*Sin[y[x2]] > 0}}, ComplexInfinity]
> ```